# regular expression for file paths

Tags: regex, unix

Hi I need a regular expression that'll give me something like this part

```
./something\", [something.sh
```

from something like this string

```
("./something\", [something.sh", ["./something\", [something.sh"], [/* 37 vars */])
```

is that possible? I'm having real trouble making this since there's that \" escape sequence and also that ',' character, so I cannot simply use match everything instead of these characters. 
I'm working on unix so it's also possible to use pipeline of few greps or something like that.
Thanks for advice.

Comment: It's perfectly possible using any of a myriad tools.  Perl, sed, awk, expr, Python - to name but five - could all do it.  The issue is 'what else are you going to do with it?'  The answer to that determines what is most useful.  A lot hinges on whether this is one off, or what variations on the match pattern will have to be coped with in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Perl you can use [Text::Balanced](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text::Balanced) which has an `extract_quotelike` function to do what you need.

You can do it manually with:

```
 /"((?:\\.|.)*?)"/
```

Basically: starting from a quote, if you see a `\`, grab the next character (even if it's a quote), else continue until you see a quote.

Comment: this work great, thanks guys :) I really appreciate every help

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '("./something\", [something.sh", ["./something\", [something.sh"], [/* 37 vars */])' |
sed 's/.*\(\.\/something\\", \[something.sh"\).*/\1/'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your input looks like Python literal. You can evaluate it as is:

```
$ echo '("./something\", [something.sh", ["./something\", [something.sh"], )' |\
> python -c'print input()[0]'
```

Output:

```
./something", [something.sh
```

Or for multiline case:

```
$ echo '("./something\", [something.sh", ["./something\", [something.sh"], )' |\
> python -c'import ast, fileinput
> for line in fileinput.input():
>      print ast.literal_eval(line)[0]'
```

Output:

```
./something", [something.sh
```

Answer (score -1):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but my suggestion is to get your regex working **quickly** first, then write the code in whatever language you use.

This website is one that I always go to first to work on my regexes: [www.regexr.com](http://www.regexr.com)

It's really nice because it'll show you groupings, too.